# how to capture part of a form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, screenshot

I want to capture part of my form and draw it in bitmap variable ...
when I use drawToBitmap() function and set `rectangle(12,40,...)`,the function just capture from 0,0 point of the form.
then what do I do to solve this?
tanks for your help

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(((int)maxWidth)+2, ((int)maxHeight)+2);
this.DrawToBitmap(bmp,new Rectangle(0,40,((int)maxWidth)+2, ((int)maxHeight)+2));
```

Comment: Show your current code please.

Comment: This isn't a personal support hotline. Nobody is sitting by just to help you. You posted your question, people will answer when they get around to browsing the site and feeling like answering. Spamming the comments every 5 minutes does not help, and in fact, will probably drive people away.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so what I did here was created a new form and added a button and a picture box.  When you click the button it cuts a rectangle out of the Form and draws it to the picturebox.

I used -100,0  which moves the image 100 pixels to the left.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The image we will be drawing on then passing to picturebox
        Bitmap bmp=new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width,pictureBox1.Height);

        using (Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
            {
                //captures the Form screenschot, and saves it into Bitmap b
                this.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));

                //this draws the image from Bitmap b starting at the specified location to Bitmap bmp 
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(b, -100, 0);
            }
        }
        //this assigns pictureBox1 the bmp Bitmap.
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
```